# Insert Statement won't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I was always using normal querys for inserting data into the database but now I want to make it with prepared statements. I'm already using statements to select data in all my files but insert never worked... And now I ran out of ideas again. Maybe someone can see what I did wrong.

```
$animeId        =   $_POST['animeId'];
$username   =   $_POST['username'];
$rating         =   $_POST['rating'];
$story          =   $_POST['story'];
$genre          =   $_POST['genre'];
$animation  =   $_POST['animation'];
$characters =   $_POST['characters'];
$music          =   $_POST['music'];

//Datum auslesen
$date =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


if($insertRating = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO anime_rating (animeId, rating, story, genre, animation, characters, music, user, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?"))
{
    $insertRating->bind_param("iiiiiiiss", $animeId, $rating, $story, $genre, $animation, $characters, $music, $username, $date);
    $insertRating->execute();
    $insertRating->close();
}
```

Comment: `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?"))` is wrong.. " After the first )

Comment: Thank you very very much.. That was the problem.. I really don't know what to say

Answer (score 5):

You have an errant comma in your query:

```
music, user,) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?                               
          ^^^
          HERE
```

It should be

```
music, user) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
```

Answer (score 1):

In the statement:

```
INSERT INTO anime_rating (
 animeId, 
 rating, 
 story, 
 genre, 
 animation, 
 characters, 
 music, 
 user /* 8 columns */) 
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?") /* 10 parameters */
```

There are 8 columns listed to insert values into and 10 parameters specified in the values section.  Also as pointed out there is the extra comma in the list of values.

The number of columns must match the number of parameters and the number of parameters binding in the following statement:

```
`$insertRating->bind_param("iiiiiiiss", $animeId, $rating, $story, $genre, $animation, $characters, $music, $username, $date);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Two errors in the statement:

```
INSERT INTO anime_rating (animeId, rating, story, genre, animation, characters, music, user,) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?"
                                                                                              ^ here and                       ^  ^
```

1. remove the comma
2. add a closing parentheses before the end of the string.
3. remove one `,?`

Furthermore you should chop one `i`s from the binding:

```
$insertRating->bind_param("iiiiiiss", $animeId, $rating, $story, $genre, $animation, $characters, $music, $username, $date);
```

Comment: Alright, I've updated the code in the question but it still don't work. Also I'm not sure if "string" is the right type to insert date in the database

Comment: You forgot the closing bracket before the end of the string (see the end of the code).

Comment: @user3084925 You are still binding 10 parameters:     `$insertRating->bind_param("iiiiiiiss", $animeId, $rating, $story, $genre, $animation, $characters, $music, $username, $date);` but specifying 9 bind variables. You need 9 columns, 9 parameters and 9 bind variables.

Comment: What error do you get. You can set the error level of php by executing it with `error_reporting(-1);` as first statement...

Answer (score 0):

```
if($insertRating = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO anime_rating (animeId, rating, story, genre, animation, characters, music, user, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?"))
```

The last (") should be placed after the first ) at the end

**New code:**

```
if($insertRating = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO anime_rating (animeId, rating, story, genre, animation, characters, music, user, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
```